# Why does SQLite throw InvalidOperationException in Unity 5.3?

Tags: c#, sqlite, exception, unity-game-engine

I am having a little issue trying to use SQLite in Unity 5.3. I have been following the SQLite setup provided in Unity Answers (http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/743400/database-sqlite-setup-for-unity.html) and I have tried to open a sqlite database with the following code:

```
 void Start()
 {
         string conn = "URI=file:" + Application.dataPath 
             + "/trajectoriesDB"; //Path to database.

         IDbConnection dbconn;
         dbconn = (IDbConnection) new SqliteConnection(conn);
         dbconn.Open();
         Debug.Log("Database open");

         dbconn.Close();
         dbconn = null;
 }
```

The problem is that, when I attempt to open the sqlite connection, Unity throws the following exception:

*InvalidOperationException: Cannot set CommandText while a DataReader is active*

I tested in a very simple scene where only this script is running, and I have also double checked that I have all the .dll I need in Assets/Plugins and the database file in Assets/.

I cannot find the root of this problem, since I do not have any DataReader in my code. Has anyone experienced the same problem before?

Thank you in advance!

**Update:**

This is the stack trace:

```
InvalidOperationException: Cannot set CommandText while a DataReader is active 

Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.set_CommandText (System.String value) 
    (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) 

Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand:set_CommandText (string) 

Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.Open () SQLiteTest.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/SQLiteTest.cs:21)
```

Comment: Can you see what line the exception is thrown at? Do you maybe have a stack trace?

Comment: The exception gets thrown while running the line dbconn.Open().

Comment: You can edit the stacktrace into the post, it won't fit the comment.